# vertical-align: middle reducing height of parent container

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

So I have this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/g5AZfKGeDVNAICPPt4WR

It has 2 divs both with a svg element in them and the only difference is that the bottom svg element has a `vertical-align: middle` and the top one does not.

My question is why when I add a `vertical-align: middle` to the svg element does the parent's `height` change from `20px` to `18px`?  I mean the svg element's `height` remains at `16px` regardless of the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: this is because `vertical-align` is not intended for positioning elements inside of other elements.  It is meant only for positioning content inside of a table cell `<td>` http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Comment: @Grapho best is to take W3C as a reference : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align / http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align  and about the <table> context : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` elements are standing on `baseline` if you do not reset `vertical-align`.

This means that you have underneath a little gap, about 0.2em,  wich is room used by letters such as : jpq...

Once you reset `vertical-align` to `middle`, `top`, `bottom`, ... , this gap fades away when not needed anymore.

See W3C as reference : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align / http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align  and within table-cell (td or displayed as such) `<table>` context : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout :)